# Как изменить input по кнопке

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть страница html, на ней кнопка submit.

```
<form action="create.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="load" value="load" />
</form>
```

Как мне при ее нажатии вставить текст в существующие на этой странице input? Например такие:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Question Title" name="question_title" required><br>
```

В целом алгоритм такой,нажав на кнопку на странице, мне надо достать данные из MySQL и вставить их в уже существующие input'ы на странице...

Comment: Так а форма при этом отправляется?

Comment: В целом нажав на кнопку submit, мне надо достать данные из MySQL, и вставить их в уже существующие input на странице...Это можно сделать с js? Возможно я в корне не так делаю, поправьте плиз...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать с помощью jQuery примерно так:

```
<form action="create.php" id="form" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="load" value="load" />
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('submit', '#form', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET'
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                console.log("success");
                $('input[name=question_title]').val(response.question_title); // Селектор и значение поменяете на свои
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

В файле `action.php` нужно сделать код который будет выполнять запрос к базе данных и возвращать данные в json и в методе done замените мой код вставки значения на свои.

Comment: А если на странице имеются несколько submit под одним <form action="create.php" id="form" method="post"> , как в этом случае повесить обработчик событий на определенную кнопку?

Comment: Для таких случаев и надо в вопросе указывать сразу всё, если несколько кнопок в 1 форме то надо событие submit сменить на click b селектор формы #form на селектор кнопки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сработало. Но у меня почему-то ничего не происходило с "url: $(this).attr('action'),", я заменил его на url: 'action.php'. В твоем случае он обращается к файлу action.php или к функции action в файле где код?

Comment: В моем случае бралось то что написано в теге form - create.php, путь брал с примера

Comment: Извини, что-то не понял. Что делает эта строчка: "url: $(this).attr('action')", она выполняет файл action.php или ищет функцию action в файле create.php? Хотя и так и так она у меня не срабатывает :)

Comment: Эта строчка брала форму <form action="create.php" method="post"> и из атрибута action брала данные, а именно: create.php